# Correlated sub-query on the same table with only one alias

Tags: subquery, sybase-sql-anywhere

I have query which look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ... AND id IN (SELECT t2.id
                     FROM my_table t2
                     WHERE id = t2.id AND ... );
```

I know in this example I could combine the two `WHERE` clauses and don't use a sub-query but this is not the point.

This query works perfectly on the DBMS I'm using (SQL Anywhere 16) but I'm wondering if the fact that `id` in the sub-query refers to `my_table.id` from the main query is a standard behavior or if I'm just lucky.

Link or reference to an RFC or any official document appreciated :)

Comment: Hmm. I would have expected `id` to be the same as `t2.id` - the "nearest" table reference is used

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right. It is. The `id` is equivalent to `t2.id` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is wrong. The standard behaviour is that in `WHERE id = ...` in the subquery the `id` refers to the closest table in scope. And that is `t2`. It would refer to `my_table` in the external query only if `t2` had no `id` column.

You are lucky though because the `WHERE id = t2.id` - which is translated as `WHERE t2.id = t2.id` is not actually needed because you used `WHERE id IN (subquery)`. If you had an `EXISTS`  version, it wouldn't work as you expected.

So, the proper ways to write the query would be either prefix all column references:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM my_table AS t1
WHERE ... AND t1.id IN 
              (SELECT t2.id
               FROM my_table t2
               WHERE --- t1.id = t2.id AND  -- remove, we don't need this 
               ... );
```

Or be very careful and prefix only when needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table AS t1
WHERE ... AND id IN 
              (SELECT id
               FROM my_table t2
               WHERE --- id = t2.id AND  -- remove, we still don't need this 
                 ... );
```

I would still prefer the `EXISTS` version for such queries:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM my_table AS t1
WHERE ... AND EXISTS
              (SELECT *
               FROM my_table t2
               WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND  -- we do need "t1". here
               ... );
```

or (if you are always very careful):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table AS t1
WHERE ... AND EXISTS
              (SELECT *
               FROM my_table t2
               WHERE t1.id = id AND    -- we need only the "t1". here
                                       -- the second ref, = id is translated
                                       -- to:   = t2.id
               ... );
```